# forgerock openam ssoadm STS configuration error while running create-sub-cfg

Tags: single-sign-on, openam, opensso

I am getting the following exception while running ssoadm's create-sub-cfg on forgerock openam13 version. I would appreciate any leads or hints to resolve this. Thanks

**Command:**

```
create-sub-cfg --servicename RestSecurityTokenService --subconfigname "test" --realm myrealm --datafile mydir1/my_realm_sts_attrs.properties
```

**Exception:**

```
Executing class, com.sun.identity.cli.schema.AddSubConfiguration.
com.sun.identity.cli.CLIException: Message:Unable to add subConfig test

    at com.sun.identity.cli.schema.AddSubConfiguration.addSubConfigToRealm(AddSubConfiguration.java:150)
    at com.sun.identity.cli.schema.AddSubConfiguration.handleRequest(AddSubConfiguration.java:103)
    at com.sun.identity.cli.SubCommand.execute(SubCommand.java:296)
    at com.sun.identity.cli.CLIRequest.process(CLIRequest.java:217)
    at com.sun.identity.cli.CLIRequest.process(CLIRequest.java:139)
    at com.sun.identity.cli.CommandManager.serviceRequestQueue(CommandManager.java:576)
    at com.sun.identity.cli.CommandManager.<init>(CommandManager.java:173)
    at com.sun.identity.cli.CommandManager.main(CommandManager.java:150)
Caused by: Message:Unable to add subConfig test

    at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceConfig.addSubConfig(ServiceConfig.java:343)
    at com.sun.identity.cli.schema.AddSubConfiguration.addSubConfig(AddSubConfiguration.java:228)
    at com.sun.identity.cli.schema.AddSubConfiguration.addSubConfigToRealm(AddSubConfiguration.java:131)
    ... 7 more
Unable to add subConfig test
Command process exited with value 127
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [OPENAM-8006](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-8006)

You probably need to replace:

```
--subconfigname "test"
```

with

```
--subconfigid "test"
```